# Open another view when button is pressed in iOS

Tags: ios, view

I am completely new to iOS development and I want to load another view when a button is pressed in a present view.

I have created a view based application and following are the codes:

//My file name is poo1

//This is poo1ViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface poo1ViewController : UIViewController 
{
 IBOutlet UIButton *fl;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *fl;
-(IBAction) ifl:(id)sender;    
@end
```

//This is poo1ViewController.m file

```
#import "poo1ViewController.h"
@implementation poo1ViewController
@synthesize fl;
-(IBAction) ifl:(id) sender {
}
```

In the `poo1ViewController.xib` I have added a button and linked it with File's Owner using Interface Builder.

Now I have added another view to this class called as `flip.xib` an just added a label inside it.

The thing I want is, when I will press the `fl` button, the `fl` button will call the method `ifl` and which in return should call the second view, i.e. `flip.xib`.

How will I do that, how can I make the `ifl` method to load `flip.xib` view ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UIViewController* flipViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"flip.xib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:flipViewController.view];
```

EDIT:

```
UIViewController* flipViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"flip" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:flipViewController.view];
```

Now click on flip.xib, click on the File's Owner on the left hand side of the design area, and change the class to UIViewController.  Now CTRL drag from File's Owner icon to the View icon right below it and select the IBOutlet View.

Comment: The program terminates when i click the button and shows the error "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGBART".

Do, I need to import that flip.xib in my implementation file

Comment: it should already be in the main bundle as long as your didn't do something crazy with it.  make sure your self.view is being created correctly.  you actually have to set self.view equal to a view before you can call [self.view addSubview:]

Comment: I have uploaded the project folder here: http://cl.ly/7zua

Please check it and can you point out the mistake

Comment: Even after editting, the App crashes 

2011-06-28 23:14:12.205 poo1[1461:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "flip" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: Right, you have to make sure the XIB file is attached to the view for the UIViewController otherwise this your arrow, so I said in the edit you have to control drag from File's Owner icon to View icon in the Interface Builder on the left hand side and select the View IBOutlet.

Comment: @bbdparrish Sorry, I missed the part after the code in EDIT. Now, it's working fine. Thanks!!

Comment: Now, if I am in flip view and it has a back button, which will redirect back to poo1ViewController.xib. How will I do/implement that.

Comment: What is i am using storyboards ?

Comment: You would create a segue in your storyboard and then trigger the segue programmatically - `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`