# How to have a UIKit button open another view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a grid of buttons in one page. I want the buttons to lead to another view when clicked. What should I add to the following action to change the view?

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"button %u -- frame: %@", button.tag, NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
}
```

The grid of buttons is created with:

```
{
    int rows = 13, columns = 4;
    UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 80*columns, 32*rows)];
    int currentTag = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {

            UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
            //  [button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0]; 
            //  [button.layer setBorderColor:UIColor blackColor]];
            button.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed: 201.0/255.0 green: 201.0/255.0 blue:201.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
            button.tag = currentTag;
            currentTag++;
            [button.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
            [button.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
            [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentTag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(80*x, 32*y, 80, 32); 
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [buttonView addSubview: button];

        }
    }

    // Center the view which contains your buttons
    CGPoint centerPoint = buttonView.center;
    centerPoint.x = self.view.center.x;
    buttonView.center = centerPoint;
    [self.view addSubview:buttonView];    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "connecting it to another view"?

Comment: I think you are confused about terms. Please explain why you want to do this.

Comment: @H2CO3 I add something is this enough?

Comment: To go to another page you need to create a new DetailView, and push it on your navigationController. Which view do you want to show? Rinju Jain's solution should work, if you substitute `Cart` with your own UIViewController class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open another view when button is pressed in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6509916/), [Button To Open New View](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11439798/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to connect an action?

```
[button addTarget:self 
         selector:@selector(buttonPressed:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(check syntax, this is by memory...)

Comment: So I see what you want. First things first: is your `buttonPressed:` correctly called when you tap a button? If so, you need to instanciate a new view[controller] and present it, see Rinju’s answer.

Comment: thanks would you please correct it and write it as an Answers, sorry I'm really new.

Answer (score 0):

Rinju's answer would work, but it needs a little more explanation. I'm not sure why exactly you would like to create this grid of buttons (more info would be nice), but if you want each button to show a new view, then tags are important!

If you want to open the same view, but with different properties shown on that view, you'd need to create a new view controller class. Let's call this `DetailViewController`.

Now, in your `buttonPressed:` method, you're going to need to instantiate this view controller and set a property of it!

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) int buttonTag;
...
//other methods, properties, etc. here
...
@end
```

Now, in your view controller where the buttons are, you can do this (for the sake of simplicity, I will assume you are using storyboards. If not, it can still be easily accomplished similar to what Rinju has done).

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailView" sender:button];
}
```

Now, you can implement the `prepareForSegue` method, which is called just before the segue fires:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailView"] ) {
        DetailViewController *detailView = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailView.buttonTag = ((UIButton*)sender).tag;
    }
}
```

Now that the tag is set for your new detail view controller, you can probably use switch statements (or better yet, a model object which is passed this buttonTag) in `viewDidLoad:` of the DetailViewController to set up the UI there. Basically what we are doing is using the tag of the button to distinguish which button was pressed, and based on this create a new view!

What you may want to do is create a `typedef enum` structure to make names for the tags instead of using raw integers. This will increase the readability of your code, and also will help you in not getting confused ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
NSLog(@"button %u -- frame: %@", button.tag, NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
Cart *crtObj=[[Cart alloc]initWithNibName:@"Cart" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:crtObj animated:YES];
[crtObj release];
}
```

Comment: That's a view controller, not a button.

Comment: on button click push to another view

Comment: @RinjuJain would you please write it with my variale I'm new to objective-c

Comment: @RinjuJain should I just add your code? I add more information above would you please check it