# Button To Open New View

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I recently became a member as I noticed that there is alot of knowledge here and I am a complete beginner at making iOS apps. I am currently making an app that works perfectly for everything I want it to do. The only problem is that I added a new button to the app and I do not know how to open a new view with it or how to hook it up to a segue or whatever will open the new view. I made the button programmatically, and as a selector I have a method called pushnext. I am trying to implement a method that will open a view but all I know is that the information in the view I want to display is contained in GridViewController.m , I do not know how to call that view and I have read many other posts here but I just can't seem to figure it out. I hope you guys can help me out. Thank you for your time.

I am also using a storyboard with the following:

Tab Bar Controller (2 icons) : then from there it splits to First View Controller and then to Navigation Controller. From Navigation Controller it is connected to Grid View Controller (What I want the button to open) and then from Grid View Controller it has a connection to Detail View Connection. Please help me if you could. I followed the guides found here if it helps you http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/design-build-a-small-business-app-custom-detail-views/

EDIT: I have added the code I have below so it is easier for you guys.

I finally see it now, the reason was because I was using the "add comment" instead of answer question.

This is what I Have in FirstViewController.h

```
-(void)pushnext;
```

Then I have my button in FirstViewController.m

```
self.roundButton = [self createButtonWithPicture:CGRectMake(110, 200, 100, 100) andLabel:@""];
[self.view addSubview:roundButton];

[self.roundButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushnext:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Also Inside of FirstViewController.m I have the implementation I want to use for opening the new view with my button:

```
-(void)pushnext{
[UIView transitionFromView:contact toView:cable duration:1.0 options UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [contact release];
   }];
```

From there I want the method pushnext to open that view for me but I just can't seem to get it. I have my button setup in the very first screen that pops up after the app loads, and I don't know what that view is called so I called it contact in my code, and I want it to open the view that has all the information contained with GridViewController.m I just don't know what to do. You suggested to use a segue to connect them but how am I supposed to connect a segue to my button. I also have the problem that my button is done programmatically not through IB. Thank you for your time and I hope you can help me. Thank you once again, I am just desperate because I have been stuck for days trying to figure it out by reading and examples and I just don't get it. I also attached a picture of my storyboard. There you might be able to see better what I am talking about, I have my button programmed in the "Tab Bar Controller" page but I want the button to open the page labeled "Grid View Controller-Second" and the image is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKs1o.png

Comment: As Darren said, either control-click and drag or just right click and drag the button to the view controller, then you should some options, push, modal, or custom, chose whichever one you want, and it should work!

Comment: He's adding his button in code, so he creates a segue from the view controller, not from the button. Then it can be called anywhere.

Comment: @Darren Yeah I am adding the button in code, so do you know which view controller I am supposed to create the segue from? Would it be the view controller that the button is in? If so how do I go about implementing a segue in code? Thanks alot for your input to all of you, you are all very helpful.

Comment: See my answer below. If you've got the view controller on a storyboard, then create the segue by dragging from the root controller your adding the button too. Then call performSegue from your button.

Comment: Hi @Darren, thanks alot for your suggestion and I was able to get it to work with what you suggested. Now my problem is that the view controller(called GridViewController that I have has another window that opens up a detail windows(called detailviewcontroller), none of the buttons that I have in the GridViewController that I open with the button using the segue work when I use the segue in modal mode, i tried to use the push mode in my segue but it crashes the app, I want to be able to open those details as well. I don't know if you can see what I am talking about in the picture I posted.

Comment: I just realized something as well, the view controller that originates the push is not a part of the same navigation controller that the view controller that is being added to the stack belongs to. So is there any other way around this besides using modal, because with modal I don't get the option to push the buttons found on the view controller I am pushing.

Comment: I'm sorry but you've lost me. You might be better starting another question about the view controllers and show some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a segue in storyboard by Ctrl+dragging from the VIEW CONTROLLER icon to your next view. Click the segue and give it a name in the attribute inspector.

Now in your button pressed code, simply call:
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName"] and it'll perform the segue to the next view.

Choose your animation type from the attribute inspector.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial should help you:

http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219

It explains pretty much exactly what you need. You create a new view, (in your case your can just use your existing one), and then create a segue to that view. Good luck.

BTW, Posting code would allow everyone to help you much better...

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a read. I wanted to post code but I couldn't find how to put it in this little box in the right format like you guys do.

Comment: I don't seem to have all those options, could it be because I am new? I don't have an option to bold or italicize and other word processing options.

Comment: What browser are you using? It came there when I was new

Comment: I updated my question with some code to help, thank you once again.