# Login view and on button click show tab controller? How?

Tags: ios

[image]

How I can do this:

```
If i press the "Einloggen" (Login) button
{
    Show TabBarController with FirstViewController
}
```

(I'm new in this and i tried to find out something about that...
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html
[Open another view when button is pressed in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509916/open-another-view-when-button-is-pressed-in-ios))

The script/functions i have is following.

```
- (IBAction)loginAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.view = self.tabBarController.view;
}
```

Then i got a black screen.
If i use the code from the stackoverflow question above, i get a error.

```
- (IBAction)loginAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIViewController* tabViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:tabViewController.view];
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I highly recommend finding a tutorial about storyboards and segues, since this is exactly what segues are for.

Comment: Nice. I used this: http://www.scott-sherwood.com/ios-5-storyboards/
Now it works... Is it possible to open the segue manually? For example: I click on "Login" and i get a loading screen. If loaded the segue is executed?

Is there a good tutorial for storyboards and segues?
I'm new in Objective C but i'm not new in php, c#, etc. :)
I like to learn iOS Developing :)

Comment: Apple has a Storyboards & Segues tutorial, and there are many online, which cover triggering a segue directly. But, to answer question, you use the `- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` method.

Comment: Sounds good. I try this AND i test some Apple tutorials about this.

Do you have a specific tutorial for me? Maybe a tutorial which you read a few years ago? ^^

Comment: If I had to pick one thing, it would be the WWDC talk on Storyboards; I think from 2012?